# Añadir elemento p con javascript dándole al botón

Tags: javascript, html, div

En mi archivo html tengo un botón y un div vació, con javascript quiero que apretando el botón, me añada dentro del div, un elemento 'p' con el texto "Hola Mundo!"

He probado con document.createElement("p"); pero nose como añadir el texto..

¿Como seria el Javascript?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
    <input type="button" value="Click en el texto" onClick="insertarTexto()">
    <div id="contenido"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado?

Comment: Es muy sencillo utilizando JQuery, inténtalo, cuando te sientas atorado nos muestras lo que intentaste y con gusto te ayudamos.

Answer (score 2):

Intenta algo así:

```js
let boton = document.querySelector('#boton');
boton.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
  let contenedor = document.querySelector('#contenido');
  let p = document.createElement('p');
  p.innerText = 'Hola, soy un p';
  contenedor.appendChild(p);
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
    <input type="button" value="Click en el texto" id="boton">
    <div id="contenido"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Te dejo el código con JQuery, es bastante sencillo utilizando la función `append`:

```js
$('#btnAdd').on('click', function(){
  $('#contenido').append('<p>Hola Mundo!</p>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
    <input id="btnAdd" type="button" value="Click en el texto">
    <div id="contenido"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Te dejo un link con la documentación: http://api.jquery.com/append/.
Espero te ayude. Saludos.